# Configurar Tomcat pra forçar Https

Tags: tomcat

Bom galera, estou precisando de um help pra configurar meu tomcat e "forçar" minha aplicação pra rodar em Https.
Estou usando o Servidor do Integrator, já consegui instalar o certificado ele roda na pasta raiz porém nas minhas aplicações ele não esta rodando ...

Comment: > Você pode alterar o **conf/server.xml** e deixar assim: <Connector port="8080" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" /> > Ou <Connector port="80" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="443" />